# Drag coefficient and lift coefficient

Tags: lift, drag, airfoil

What happens if drag coefficient increases but the lift coefficient remain the same?

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit? What prompted it? What is unclear to you? "what happens" to what? the fuel efficiency, the L/D ratio, the flight range, ... ?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you'll need to increase the power in order to keep your airspeed and stay airborne. The extra power will be spent in fighting the extra drag... Besides, you'll have to reduce AoA in order to keep total lift equal to the weight and thus stay at the same altitude...